# woocommerce displaying products of a specific page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

First sorry for my english, is not my first language.

So what I want to do is to get the products of a particular page, using the get variable, so this is my current code...

```
$page = 0;
if(isset($_GET['pagina'])){
    $page = $_GET['pagina'];
}
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product','posts_per_page' => 1, 'page' => $page);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 

    echo get_the_title();
endwhile;
```

I though the parameter `'page' => $page` will do exactly that... but it seems I was wrong and maybe I understood it wrong when I was reading it.

So example if I have 2 products: `product_1` and `product_2` and my `posts_per_page` is `1` what Im trying to archive is that

if I type `http://myurl.com/?pagina=1` will show `product_1`

and if I type `http://myurl.com/?pagina=2` will show `product_2`

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:** I think my english failed to communicate my problem so ima try explaning in other example

What I want is to get the products that are suppose to go in the page I get tru $_GET So if I have to use my own pagination, it will look something like this:

```
$page = 1;
$posts_per_page = 1;
if(isset($_GET['pagina'])){
    $page = $_GET['pagina'];
}
$start_from = $posts_per_page * ($page-1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products LIMIT $start_from,$posts_per_page"
```

Comment: Use page_id, not page (if the ID is the parameter you are getting from the pagina var.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: @TheJ the parameter im getting from the GET is the current page number of the pagination, I would like to retrieve the products that are in that page, in my example I use `posts_per_page => 1` but I wouldn't use that, it was just a example, so what im trying to say is if GET['pagina'] == 2 then get the products on page 2, if would implement this myself, the query will look something like 

`$start_from = ($page-1) * $posts_per_page;`

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products LIMIT $start_from,$posts_per_page";`

Comment: @TheJ I edited my question, in the comments its hard to read the code

Comment: Ah I see what you want to do. That's definitely not the right way to go about it. Also, direct SQL calls are almost never needed.
I'd build a simple WP Query, using the `offset` (that you can calculate dynamically) parameter and `post_type = 'product'`. So for each page, then you get your offset  value with the number of `posts_per_page` * `page`.

Comment: @TheJ I think that this `offset` parameter answers all my questions, didn't know there was one, Ill give it I try and come back

Comment: @TheJ yep, all I needed was someone to tell me `offset` was a parameter, thanks man, post an answer below and ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a simple [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), using the `offset` parameter and `post_type => 'product'`.

So for each page, you calculate your `offset` value with `$posts_per_page * $page`.